# IPFS: Duplicate Pinning- Pin a file in two different locations?

Tags: ipfs

I'm currently using Filebase - a paid IPFS pinning service - to pin my IPFS files. Filebase are still in beta, so the prices are low but could rise in the future.

Therefore I'd like to keep copies of all my files on a drive on my home computer too just in case Filebase has problems,outages, etc. in the future. My local computer files will be an IPFS node itself.

Should I pin these local files on my computer as well? Or will duplicate pinning cause problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can totally pin the local files on your local IPFS node running on your home computer. However, it is more likely that your node on your home computer will crash or the machine itself will corrupt than Filebase. It's true Filebase is a centralized service with a single point of failure, but they are likely running several IPFS nodes pinning your files and storing them long-term on the Sia network.

To safest option is to explore storing your data on [Filecoin](https://www.filecoin.com/), which is equivalent to Sia in the sense that it is for long-term persistence (which IPFS is not). Think of IPFS as the decentralized version of Redis. It can cache and store information, but it's not designed to store them like a database is.

Comment: Check out web3.strorage if you want an easy way to do this too